# AngularJS - Show div content based on Id clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show

**Header Links HTML**

```
<ul ng-controller="pageRouteCtrl">
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="home" class="" ng-click="getPageId('live-view')">LIVE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a ng-click="getPageId('playback')">PLAYBACK</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Ctrl**

```
myApp.controller('pageRouteCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.getPageId = function(id) {
        $rootScope.route = id;
    }

});
```

**Main Page HTML**

```
//should be visible on page load and until playback link is clicked
<div id="live-view" ng-show="route == 'live-view'">
SOME CONTENT
</div>

//will be hidden initially on page load
<div id="playback" ng-show="route == 'playback'">
SOME CONTENT
</div>
```

The above code works and display `<div>` content based on link clicked. Subsequently when user clicks on either Live or Playback, div content will be shown.

How do I make `live-view` div show by default on page load ?

Answer (score 0):

Write following code in controller:

```
myApp.controller('pageRouteCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) { 

$rootScope.route = 'live-view'; 

$scope.getPageId = function(id) {
      $rootScope.route = id;
         }
      });
```

Comment: And what will happen when user clicks on `playback` link ? Could you post answer related to above code ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy, as default `live-view` div show on load page, when user click `playback` link  playback div will show and live-view div will hide